# ReSharper doing the wrong thing adding Register directives

Tags: c#, asp.net, resharper

ReSharper (7.1.25.234) does the wrong thing when adding register directives.

1. Create `/Controls/ComplexField.ascx`
2. In `APageWithABunchOfFields.aspx`, refer to the new control:

   ```
   <%@ Page Title="A page with a bunch of fields" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Layouts/Site.Master" %>
   <myproj:ComplexField runat="server" />
   ```
3. ReSharper offers to generate a `<%@ Register %>` directive, which leads to this:

   ```
   <%@ Page Title="A page with a bunch of fields" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Layouts/Site.Master" %>
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="myproj" Namespace="MyProject.Controls" Assembly="MyProject" %>
   <myproj:ComplexField runat="server" />
   ```

The problem is, that won't find or execute `ComplexField.ascx` (note though that a `ComplexField` instance does get contructed). What ReSharper *should* generate is:

```
<%@ Page Title="A page with a bunch of fields" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Layouts/Site.Master" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myproj" TagName="ComplexField" Src="~/Controls/ComplexField.ascx" %>
<myproj:ComplexField runat="server" />
```

In other words, ReSharper is registering the control by namespace instead of by source path. The issue ReSharper causes is that ASP.NET doesn't execute the `ComplexField.ascx` file when the page is loaded!

Is this a bug/missing feature in ReSharper or a problem with my understanding of Register directives?

Comment: Sorry, but you need to add more code to your samples. We cannot read between the lines.

Comment: @DmitryOsinovskiy - I tried to expand the question slightly; see if that helps.

Comment: Just create issue in ReSharper tracker with repro project. It will be more effective.